# What kind of electric motors are used to build industrial robot arms?

Tags: motors

I'm fascinated by how robot arm nowadays can combine precision with operating speed (e.g. KIRA by Motorized Precision).

I can imagine building a robot arm with stepper motors would be pretty precise but (from my experiences with stepper motors) wouldn't be able to deliver the speed.

Servo motors (from my experience using them in combination with a raspberry pi) would be a bit faster but not fast enough.

DC Brushed motors are lack position awareness.

I don't have experience with brushless motors but I've mainly seen them being used for drones which is quite a different use case.

So I want to know what kind of motor might in those kinds of industrial robot arms that are able to do the split between speed and precision.

Comment: permanent magnet synchronous motors gain a lot of attentions recently.

Comment: Look up "Harmonic Drive" - it's a gearbox not a motor, but is able to provide incredible precision with zero backlash - this coupled with a DC motor and encoder, is a good basis for a joint.